# Can't download export file - The path is not writable

Tags: magento2, export, permissions, magento2.4

System - Data Transfer - Export

I get this error when I try to download export csv file

> The path "/magento/var/export/catalog_product_20201008_102857.csv" is
> not writable.

var/export folder permission is 777 and the generated csv file is 664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the word permissions is part of your error message, best to focus on permissions (usually). I can see your point is spontaneously giving confusion. But it is worth persisting. Given I don't know your environment or setup initially, of ocurse it is very vague but the below should help.

[image]

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-set-two-users